# Changing the Slider Height

Tags: flutter, slider, android-alertdialog

I've tried a lot, but I can't change the height of AlertDialog when I use Slider. I saw here on the Forum the suggestion to use ConstrainedBox. Did n't work. Is there a better way to show the Slider?

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ConstrainedBox(
      constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 100.0),
      child: AlertDialog(
        title: Text('Selecione a velocidade'),
          content: Container(
          child: Slider(            
            value: _fontSize,
            label: _fontSize.round().toString(),
            min: 20,
            max: 200,
            divisions: 18,
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                _fontSize = value;
              });
            },
          ),
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            onPressed: () {
              print('cancelar');
              // Use the second argument of Navigator.pop(...) to pass
              // back a result to the page that opened the dialog
              Navigator.pop(context, _fontSize);
            },
            child: Text('Cancelar'),
          ),
          FlatButton(
            onPressed: () {
              print('salvar');
              // Use the second argument of Navigator.pop(...) to pass
              // back a result to the page that opened the dialog
              Navigator.pop(context, _fontSize);
            },
            child: Text('Salvar'),
          ),
          FlatButton(
            onPressed: () {
              print('aplicar');
              // Use the second argument of Navigator.pop(...) to pass
              // back a result to the page that opened the dialog
              Navigator.pop(context, _fontSize);
            },
            child: Text('Aplicar'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

I attached an image showing how AlertDialog looks.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define the height for the `Container` which outside the `Slider`.

```
 content: Container(
          height:50,  // define any height you want here
          child: Slider(
```

This is how the output looked like.

[image]

Comment: Tranks... The solution was simple and obvious :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. 
[Dart pad to show your output](https://dartpad.dev/b6409e10de32b280b8938aa75364fa7b)

Let me know if it work out for you or not.

Code is here

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FittedBox(
      child: AlertDialog(
        title: Text('Selecione a velocidade'),
          content: Container(
          child: Slider(            
            value: _fontSize,
            label: _fontSize.round().toString(),
            min: 20,
            max: 200,
            divisions: 18,
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                _fontSize = value;
              });
            },
          ),
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            onPressed: () {
              print('cancelar');
              // Use the second argument of Navigator.pop(...) to pass
              // back a result to the page that opened the dialog
              Navigator.pop(context, _fontSize);
            },
            child: Text('Cancelar'),
          ),
          FlatButton(
            onPressed: () {
              print('salvar');
              // Use the second argument of Navigator.pop(...) to pass
              // back a result to the page that opened the dialog
              Navigator.pop(context, _fontSize);
            },
            child: Text('Salvar'),
          ),
          FlatButton(
            onPressed: () {
              print('aplicar');
              // Use the second argument of Navigator.pop(...) to pass
              // back a result to the page that opened the dialog
              Navigator.pop(context, _fontSize);
            },
            child: Text('Aplicar'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```